# Powershell script is failing when I am trying to replace parameters using ForEach-Object

Tags: powershell

Function in my PowerShell script is as follows:

```
function replace-file-content([string] $path, [string] $replace, [string] $replacewith) {
    (Get-Content $path) |
      Foreach-Object -replace{$replace,$replacewith}|
        Out-File $path

}
```

Error I am getting is:

> ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'Process'. Cannot convert the "-replace" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".

Comment: `Foreach-Object {$_ -replace $replace,$replacewith}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Foreach-Object -replace{$replace,$replacewith}`

Since [`Foreach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) is a *cmdlet*, the tokens that follow it are parsed in [*argument mode*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing), meaning that they are either interpreted:

- as *parameter names*, if they start with `-`
- as *positional arguments* otherwise.

While [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) is an *operator* in *expression mode*, passed to `ForEach-Object` it is instead interpreted as a *parameter name*.

However, `ForEach-Object` has no *parameter* named `-replace`, which explains the error you saw (in PSv2; in PSv5.1+ (and possibly earlier), it is a different error that is, regrettably, *less* obvious).

What you meant to do was to use `-replace` *inside a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks)* (`{ ... }`) - a reusable piece of PowerShell code executed on demand - which itself forms a *new* parsing context; you can pass such a script block to `ForEach-Object` *positionally*, in which case it *implicitly* binds to the
`-Process` parameter, or explicitly with parameter name `-Process`; that script block specifies the code to execute for each input object.

Inside the script block, you must use [automatic variable `$_`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) to refer to the input object at hand:

```
# Same as: Foreach-Object -Process { $_ -replace $replace, $replacewith }
Foreach-Object { $_ -replace $replace, $replacewith }
```

A statement starting with `$` is parsed in *expression mode*, in which you can then use *operators* such as `-replace`, as shown above.